# Android mediaController back button

Tags: android, back, mediacontroller

I have a PagerView with ImageView and VideoView, and when I change page to a videoView I have show the mediaController, when I have an imageView I have to hide it. So i'm using addOnPageChangeListener on to change the visibility on onPageSelected. That works well, the problem is that I can't use the back button when it's visibility is GONE, to make it work when VISIBLE I did this:

```
        mediaController = new MediaController(context){
            @Override
            public void hide() {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    super.hide();
                    Activity a = (Activity)context;
                    a.finish();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        };
```

How could i make it work on both cases?

Comment: you can use activity's backPress method

Comment: Already tried, it's not called, its only called if i add super.hide() on mediaController hide function, but that way, i cant make the controller not hide when a videoView is visible.